# javascript object remove

Tags: javascript

Please excuse my question if it doesnt make much sense.

I am using javascript to create a dom element 
to do that i create an object ( `obj ={}`) and fill out the properties as i go, one of which is  the dom element to be created. once the element is created and appended to the document i do not need the object to occupy any space in the memory so i was thinking i should remove it.
how would i go about doing that?
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object's going to exist in memory as soon as it's in the DOM, and the obj property that holds it is really holding a reference to it, not a copy. So as far as I know, the memory required to keep the reference as a property of obj should be negligible. In which case I wouldn't worry about removing it at all.

Comment: If you're using jQuery plugins such as [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net) then it **does** matter: For example, if you intend to re-initialize such a table there is no clean way to do it. See [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1244/how-to-re-initialize-a-datatable-reload-it-from-scratch/p1) if you're interested in more details regarding this control and its issues regarding unloading it.

Answer (score 3):

here is how:

```
my_var = null;

//or remove it
delete my_var;
```

Comment: what if the object is referenced only by ' this ' in a function?

' delete this ' doesn't seem to work

Comment: I am not sure he has mentioned if it is referenced by this.

Comment: I don't think you can delete an object from within one of its member functions. Keep a reference to it and delete it somewhere else

Comment: there's a common misconception about what `delete` does: it's not like C++' `delete`, ie it won't trigger object destruction; all it does is remove properties from objects - it doesn't work on local variables at all; `delete foo.bar` and `delete foo[42]` are ok, whereas `delete foo` will do nothing if `foo` is a local variable (and even throw an syntax error in strict-mode ECMAScript 5)

Answer (score 0):

if you define you object as locale like

var obj ={}

it will be automatically undefined at the end of the function.